# How to stop EditText from taking whole width in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have below layout which basically show "messages" as bubble slimier to built-in "Messages". I just need to show also an arrow image on the right, the image is shown, but the problem is:

when the `"EditText"` have lots of text, it takes whole width, `ImageView` is still show but appear in top of the "`EditText`"

How could I stop "EditText" from taking whole width, I tried `android:layout_weight` but it didn't work

any clue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <!--    android:background="#FFDBE2ED"-->
 <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:background="#00DBE2ED"
          >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00DBE2ED"
        android:weightSum="1.0" 
       >
    <!--  android:layout_gravity="center" -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:editable="false" 
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Hello bubbles!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
            android:layout_weight=".70" 
             />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="0dip"

            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="2dip"
            android:text="Hello bubbles!"

           android:textColor="#b9dcdcdc"
           android:textSize="11sp"    
            android:layout_below="@+id/comment"

            />
           <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/aquaplayicon"
    android:src="@drawable/aquaplayicon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
     android:onClick="onClickGirl"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_weight=".30"

    />

    </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ImageView` before `EditText`
and use `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/aquaplayicon"`in the EditText

and `layout_weight` does not work for `RelativeLayout`

Edit: try this

```
<LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/wrapper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="#00DBE2ED"
            android:orientation="vertical"
              > 
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00DBE2ED"
            android:weightSum="1.0" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           >
        <!--  android:layout_gravity="center" -->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:editable="false" 
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="Hello bubbles!"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                 />

               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/aquaplayicon"
                android:src="@drawable/aquaplayicon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onClickGirl"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        />

        </LinearLayout>
         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_margin="0dip"

                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:text="Hello bubbles!"

               android:textColor="#b9dcdcdc"
               android:textSize="11sp"    
                android:layout_below="@+id/comment"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it, but still it didn't stop EditText from taking whole space when there is lots of text in EditText.

Answer (score 1):

set EditText to some predefined size:

say,

android:layout_width="80dp"

Comment: using fixed width can be a problem when using different screen sizes/resolution. Its good to set the width dynamically, based on the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to change your `RelativeLayout` to a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout` and add the elements from left to right. Then you can use android:layout_weight to make sure everything is shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Give layout_weight to the components within your linearlayout and set android:layout_width="0dip"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Some background resource and want your EditText size to stay the same and the drawable then set

```
andrid:maxEms="5";    // You can use any small value,
```

Other wise use

```
andrid:maxEms         // For Max width with respect to number of character (Text)
android:maxWidth      // For max with in dp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing android:layout_width="fill_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content"